# Looping to calculate sum of adjacent values while skipping blanks

Tags: r, loops, time-series, spss

I have a time series of emotional responses and I want to calculate a variable from the sum of absolute differences between these responses. For example, I have 10 variables for the intensity of sadness for T1-T10. However, there is some missing data for some participants, because some only responded for e.g. T1-5 or T1-8. So the number of responses I have for every participant varies.

Now I want to calculate a new variable (SAD_s) from the sum of absolute differences between these variables like this (T1s is the intensity of sadness for T1, T2s for T2 and so on):

```
COMPUTE SAD_s=abs(T2s-T1s)+abs(T3s-T2s) + abs(T4s-T3s) +abs(T5s-T4s)+abs(T6s-T5s) + abs(T7s-T6s) +abs(T8s-T7s)+abs(T9s-T8s) + abs(T10s-T9s) .
EXECUTE.
```

However, that only works for participants with the maximum of possible responses. For everyone else  with missing data I get no value.

How can I make this work for participants who have missing data at the end of the time series (e.g. missing values from T7 onward, but complete data before that)? In principle, I would also like a solution for participants with missing values in between (e.g. T1-T7 complete, T8 missing, T9-T10 complete), but I would prioritize the former.

I also have a variable indicating the number of Ts participants responded to. I have a faint idea that I need to use a loop that is being repeated the number of times this variable indicates, but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: easily done in spss - just one question - if say T8 is missing, do you want `abs(T9-T7)` to replace `abs(T8-T7)+abs(T9-T8)`

Comment: No, in that case I would want to calculate (T2s-T1s)+abs(T3s-T2s) + abs(T4s-T3s) +abs(T5s-T4s)+abs(T6s-T5s) + abs(T7s-T6s) + abs(T10s-T9s)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just skip the missing value and still calculate differences between all pairs of adjacent valid values, you can go this way:

```
compute #lstvr=T1.
compute sad_s=0.
do repeat vr=T2 to T10.
  if not missing(vr) and not missing (#lstvr) sad_s=sad_s+abs(vr-#lstvr).
  if not missing(vr) #lstvr=vr.
end repeat.
```

If, as I understand from your comment, you do not want to compare values from the two sides of a missing value, just fix the second line within the loop like this:

```
compute #lstvr=vr. /* instead of "if not missing(vr) #lstvr=vr."
```

Comment: Thank you! The values in this variable seem unrealistically high though in my case. Maybe I didn't adapt this to my dataset correctly. Anyhow, I found a simpler solution to my problem by using SUM command in my original syntax code: COMPUTE SAD_s=SUM(abs(T2s-T1s),abs(T3s-T2s),abs(T4s-T3s),abs(T5s-T4s),abs(T6s-T5s), abs(T7s-T6s),abs(T8s-T7s),abs(T9s-T8s),abs(T10s-T9s)) .
EXECUTE.

Comment: That's a good solution if you only have 9 pairs like here, but better use a loop If ever your time series has (many) more points. As for the high value - I successfully tested my code on an example - If you want to pursue this further please add some sample data to your post (use the EDIT button) to we can test answers on a common example.